# Restarting The Jobs In ApScheduler Python When the Wsgi Server is Restarted

Tags: python, flask, cron, mod-wsgi, apscheduler

I'm using python Apscheduler to schedule my jobs. All my jobs are stored as a cron job and use the BackgroundScheduler. I've the following codes:

```
def letschedule():
    jobstores = {
        'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url=app_jobs_store)
    }
    executors = {
        'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(20),
        'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
    }
    job_defaults = {
        'coalesce': False,
        'max_instances': 1,
        'misfire_grace_time':1200
    }
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores, executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone=utc)
    #jobstores=jobstores, executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone=utc
    return scheduler
```

And I start the job scheduler as follow in the app:

```
sch = letschedule()
sch.start()
log.info('the scheduler started')
```

And I've the following add job function.

```
def addjobs():


    jobs = []
    try:
        sch.add_job(forecast_jobs, 'cron', day_of_week=os.environ.get("FORECAST_WEEKOFDAY"),  
            id="forecast",
             replace_existing=False,week='1-53',hour=os.environ.get("FORECAST_HOUR"), 
             minute=os.environ.get("FORECAST_MINUTE"), timezone='UTC')
        jobs.append({'job_id':'forecast', 'type':'weekly'})

        log.info('the forecast added to the scheduler')
    except BaseException as e:
        log.info(e)
        pass
    try:
        sch.add_job(insertcwhstock, 'cron', 
            id="cwhstock_data", day_of_week='0-6', replace_existing=False,hour=os.environ.get("CWHSTOCK_HOUR"),
            minute=os.environ.get("CWHSTOCK_MINUTE"),
            week='1-53',timezone='UTC')
        jobs.append({'job_id':'cwhstock_data', 'type':'daily'})
        log.info('the cwhstock job added to the scheduler')
    except BaseException as e:
        log.info(e)
        pass
    return json.dumps({'data':jobs})
```

I use this in the flask application, I call the /activatejobs and the jobs are added to the scheduler and it works fine. However when I restart the wsgi server, the jobs aren't started again, I've to remove the .sqlite file and add the jobs again. What I want is the jobs are supposed to be restarted automatically once the scheduler is started (if there are already jobs in the database.) 
I tried to get such result trying some ways, but couldn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So in the same .sh you restart your `uwsgi` you can add a line like `python startscheduler.py`  or similar, so it will run same time.

Comment: Ya that could be done, but I already use sqlite to store the jobs, since the scheduler is started when I restart the mod_wsgi, so I suppose the schduler should recall the jobs from the database. I don't know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Your sqlite is in memory only store, so you might need to use mysql or postgres if you need a more durable solution. Also rq or celery can handle jobs on a more robust way.

Comment: Oh, I thought, sqlite would act like any other storage. Because even after the server is restarted, I can get the list of jobs from the sqlite. So its not memory only storage I guess. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: It could be the way you use it is in-memory only. If you have a way to read you should be able then restart those jobs, but looks like they are no longer running, so you have to force them to be restarted somehow.

Comment: Ya, the only way to force them to restart seems : delete the sqlite file, and call the activatejobs again, which in my case I won't want.

Comment: I also had  a problem of jobs not being restarted after server or app restarted. explicitly defining which jobstore I am adding the job fixed my issue. So I started adding jobs with job_stores for example scheduler.add_job(jobstore='mongo', trigger='cron', minute=8)

Comment: Oh really, but as I've been suggested by the apscheduler team, I couldn't use flaks/wsgi if I want my jobs to be automatically restarted, so I created a separate process for the jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem using FastApi framework. I could solve the problem after add this code to my app.py:

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
pg_job_store = SQLAlchemyJobStore(engine=my_engine)
scheduler.add_jobstore(jobstore=pg_job_store, alias='sqlalchemy')
scheduler.start()
```

Adding this code, after I restart the application server I could see apscheduler logs searching for jobs:

```
2021-10-20 14:37:53,433 - apscheduler.scheduler - INFO     => Scheduler started
2021-10-20 14:37:53,433 - apscheduler.scheduler - DEBUG    => Looking for jobs to run
Jobstore default:
    No scheduled jobs
Jobstore sqlalchemy:
    remove_from_db_job (trigger: date[2021-10-20 14:38:00 -03], next run at: 2021-10-20 14:38:00 -03)
2021-10-20 14:37:53,443 - apscheduler.scheduler - DEBUG    => Next wakeup is due at 2021-10-20 14:38:00-03:00 (in 6.565892 seconds)
```

It works for me.